# rank and orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

If $A$ is an orthogonal projection matrix onto a subspace $W$ of dimension $2$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$,

how can I prove that 
$${\rm rank}(A) = 2$$
$${\rm rank}(A^2) = 2$$
$${\rm rank}(A^2) = 1$$
$${\rm rank}(A^2) = 4$$

Comment: $A^2=A$ surely? What do you want the rank of $A^2$ to be?

Comment: rank(A) is 2, 1 and 4?

Comment: @Jonas yes that is correct

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown where do you get A^2 = A?

Comment: But how would rank(A^2) be three different values at the same time for a fixed A?

Comment: @Jonas I apologize. My question wasn't written clearly. It's more so proving or disproving among the selections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then $Ax \in W$ by definition of projection, so since $W$ is two-dimensional, it follows that $\text{rank}(A) = 2$. Also, by the definition of projection, $A^2 = A$. So for the same reasons as before, $\text{rank}(A^2) = 2$. Orthogonality of $A$ is not needed.